# Jenkins JIRA plugin, update status of ticket after several services were build successfully

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jira

Our development team is split, AEM (frontend) and backend services.

For the AEM team, when a ticket reaches the status "code merged", whenever a Jenkins build is started, those tickets are (after the build is finished) automatically moved to a different status ("available on environment)

The team works on AEM (Adobe Experience Manager) and the code base is a single repository.

I want to do the same setup for the backend services team. However, it is possible that a single ticket involved changes in multiple backend services.

1. payment-service
2. credit-card-service
3. order-service

There is currently a single Jenkins job with a build parameter (dropdown) of all services. This means that in order for a user to get the change on an environment, they need to start the "createRelease" job three times, every time selecting a different project (= service) name from the dropdown.

This, as a result, means that the JIRA ticket status should only be updated if all related services had a successful build. Anyone an idea how we best tackle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a standard Jenkins job with a dropdown parameter, you should use a Jenkins pipeline with 4 stages:

- payment-service build
- credit-card-service build
- order-service build
- JIRA ticket update (if the three previous stages are successful)

Will it help?